# Issue with substring to Write in a CSV file in Java

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist

I'm working on a java project. I am using JDK1.7 with eclipse on Win7.
I have a .csv file with following records:

```
317213,384641,1,Closed,-119,-1
317246,317247,1,Closed,8.8,-0.2
317264,317246,1,Closed,92.3,-7.2
317264,317246,2,Open,0,0
```

Further, I am extracting these records from the file, updating records, storing again in the file. When I'm fetching the updated records, I am getting the following output:

```
"317213","384641","1","Closed","-118.9","-1.0"
"317246","317247","1","Closed","20.8","-0.1"
"317264","317246","1","Closed","104.1","-5.4"
"317264","317246","2","Open","0.0","0.0"
```

Clearly, the problem is "..." in each field of the record.

Here is my code:

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

address = path + "/networkFile/1/11/B20branch1t.csv" ;
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(address));
List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String[] subentries = {}; 
String answer = "317213,384641,1,Closed,-119,-1,317246,317247,1,Closed,8.8,-0.2,317264,317246,1,Closed,92.3,-7.2,317264,317246,2,Open,0,0";

String[] entries = answer.split(",");
for( c = 0 ; c < entries.length ; c+=6 ) 
{
    subentries = Arrays.copyOfRange(entries, c, c+6) ; 
}
writer.writeNext(subentries);
writer.close();
```

May be the problem is because of `writer.writeNext()`, which may write each record with "...".
Is the any other way to achieve the same? Can I achieve this using mentioned "data" List?

Comment: Where does the CSVWriter class come from?

Comment: import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

Comment: Where do you read the file?

Comment: No need of reading, just overwriting.

Comment: Also, why the for loop? Why not just `subentries = answer.split(",");`? Or even `writer.writeNext(answer.split(","), false);`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `writeNext(String[]);` you can use [writeNext(String[] nextLine, boolean applyQuotesToAll)](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVWriter.html#writeNext(String[],%20boolean)) which will add quotes only to the values that contain special characters.

Also, I think there is a problem with the loop, I think it should be something like this:

```
for(int c = 0; c <= entries.length - 6; c+=6 ){
    subentries = Arrays.copyOfRange(entries, c, c+6) ; 
    writer.writeNext(subentries, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me!

```
writer.writeNext(subentries, false);
```

Thanks @S.L. Barth @Shadow